# How to integrate reCAPTCHA v3 in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, register, contact-form, captcha

I am integrating reCAPTCHA v3 in my magento on registration page and contact form, but I am not getting any help on this as this is new version. Can some one guide me on this. I found we can create keys from https://g.co/recaptcha/v3.

Answer (score -1):

You have to first getting site key and secret key from google recaptcha then you have to just add below code in your phtml file for any forms.

```
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=reCAPTCHA_site_key"></script>
  <script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
         ...
      });
  });
  </script>
```

You have to also follow this link https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3 for more information.Thanks.

Comment: Hi Raj, I have checked this code already but I am not sure how I can use this code as its missing something  with . . .

Answer (score -1):

For Integrating Google reCaptcha in magento 1.9, You need to add following code in your phtml file.

```
<form id="form-id" onsubmit="return checkcaptcha();" action="">
                        .....
                        .....
    <div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="reCaptcha_site_key" data-callback="enableBtn"></div>
    <span class='captcha-error'><?php echo __('Please check the the captcha form.') ?></span>
                        .....
                        .....
</form>
<style>
   .captcha-error {
      display: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: red;
      text-align: center;
  }
</style>

<?php $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode(); ?>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=<?php echo $storeCode ?>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if("js-recaptcha-reset's resetRecaptcha" === "yes") {
      if(typeof grecaptcha !== 'undefined' && grecaptcha && grecaptcha.reset) {
              grecaptcha.reset();
      }
    }
    function checkcaptcha() {
        if ((jQuery('#g-recaptcha-response').val()) == '') {
          jQuery('.captcha-error').css('display', 'inline-block');
          return false;
      } else {
          jQuery('.captcha-error').css('display', 'none');
      }
    }
 </script>
```

checkcaptcha() function for check validation of Google reCaptcha.

I hope this will useful for you.:)

Comment: Hi Emipro, where we have to add "Secret key" to verify captcha. 
Also I was asking for V3 captcha, but I am trying to test this code too.

Comment: I have added you code by replacing "reCaptcha_site_key" only and captcha is visible on register page but its not working as captcha verification is not done when I submit button